# removing time from date&time variable in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

i have a variable consisting of 300k records with dates and the date look like
2015-02-21 12:08:51
from that date i want to remove time

type of date variable is pandas.core.series.series

This is the way i tried

```
from datetime import datetime,date
date_str = textdata['vfreceiveddate']  
format_string = "%Y-%m-%d"
then = datetime.strftime(date_str,format_string)
```

some Random ERROR

In the above code textdata is my datasetname and vfreceived date is a variable consisting of dates
How can i write the code to remove the time from the datetime.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Assuming all your datetime strings are in a similar format then just convert them to datetime using [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) and then call the `dt.date` attribute to get just the date portion:

```
In [37]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2015-02-21 12:08:51']})
df
Out[37]:
                  date
0  2015-02-21 12:08:51
In [39]:

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date
df
Out[39]:
         date
0  2015-02-21
```

### EDIT

If you just want to change the display and not the dtype then you can call `dt.normalize`:

```
In[10]:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.normalize()
df

Out[10]: 
        date
0 2015-02-21
```

You can see that the dtype remains as `datetime`:

```
In[11]:
df.dtypes

Out[11]: 
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 9):

You're calling `datetime.datetime.strftime`, which requires as its first argument a `datetime.datetime` instance, because it's an **unbound method**; but you're passing it a string instead of a datetime instance, whence the obvious error.

You can work purely at a string level if that's the result you want; with the data you give as an example, `date_str.split()[0]` for example would be exactly the `2015-02-21` string you appear to require.

Or, you **can** use `datetime`, but then you need to **parse** the string first, not **format** it -- hence, str**p**time, *not* str**f**time:

```
dt = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date = dt.date()
```

if it's a `datetime.date` object you want (but if all you want is the string form of the date, such an approach might be "overkill":-).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [`floor`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html#pandas.Series.dt.floor). For example:

```
s = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp('2015-02-21 12:08:51'), pd.Timestamp('2017-05-23 09:13:47')])

s.dt.floor('D') # Rounding down to days.
```

Output:

```
0   2015-02-21
1   2017-05-23
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note that you get the same datetime format. Because the hours, minutes and seconds are set to zero, they are not displayed.

Answer (score 0):

simply writing

`date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")` will remove the Hour min & sec

Answer (score 0):

Pandas does not support a Pandas-native "date" type.

The examples here showing the use of `.dt.date` will generate Python Date objects, and construct a series of object pointers to these dates.  You've now increased your storage and reduced the likelihood of any vectorised operations on the data.  Also, none of the Pandas type checkers will recognise the column as being any kind of date (or datetime) column, as it's now just a Python object column no Pandas.

If this is really what you want, then fine.  However, I would normally elect to *only* do this just before serialising to another format (csv, JSON, etc.) so that these can benefit from not having the time component output.

If I *really* want a "date" within a DataFrame, my personal choice is to use `.astype("datetime64[D]")`; this is a quick way to zero-out the time component - it's still there really, but I can now do all of my date related calcs unfettered by the time component.