# Removing time from a date column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas data frame that had a Date (string) which i could convert and set it up as a index using the `set_index` and `to_datetime` functions

```
usd2inr_df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(usd2inr_df['Date']), inplace=True)
```

but the resulting dataframe has the time portion which i wanted to remove ...

**2023-02-14 00:00:00**

I wanted to have it as **2023-02-14**

How do i setup the call such that, i can get have the date without the time portion as a index on my dataframe

```
usd2inr_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(usd2inr_df['Date']).dt.normalize()
usd2inr_df.set_index(usd2inr_df['date'])
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310116/removing-time-from-datetime-variable-in-pandas has your answer

Comment: First, columns `date` and `Date` are not the same. That may be the source of your issue. Second, you have the code already: `s.dt.normalize()` (though I prefer `s.dt.round('D')` because it is clearer) will truncate your time portion away. When all time portions are sent to 00:00:00, Pandas will pretend it is not there.

Answer (score 1):

1. Using the `.to_datetime()` method, converts a `Series` to a pandas `datetime` object.
2. Using the `Series.dt.date`, returns a 'yyyy-mm-dd' date form.
3. Using the `DataFrame.index`, sets the index of the dataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

# create a dataFrame as an example
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Example'],'Date': ['2023-02-14 10:01:11']})

print(df)

# convert 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' to 'yyyy-mm-dd'.
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.date

# set 'Date' as index
df.index = df['Date']

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
      Name                 Date
0  Example  2023-02-14 10:01:11

-------------------------------------------------------

               Name        Date
Date
2023-02-14  Example  2023-02-14
```

Comment: add some sample outputs and this answer would be perfect.

Comment: @TharakaDevinda Thanks for your improvement suggestion 