# Remove eveything after a specifc number in Date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, object

I have a column in a data frame with Date in below format
2016-01-13 00:00:00
The abovecolumn is in object datatype format.

While I run the code I need to get answer as
2016-01-13
Without time in it.

what would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

Comment: Try using .dt.date:

Sample code: 
df['only_date'] = df['datetime_column'].dt.date

more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310116/removing-time-from-datetime-variable-in-pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the datetime module to get rid of the time component from a date column. Maybe try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

# Assuming your date column is named 'Date' in the DataFrame df
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  # Convert the column to datetime type
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.date  # Extract only the date portion

# If you want to convert the column back to string format
df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
```

The 'Date' column is first converted to datetime format using `pd.to_datetime()`. Then, we take the date component of the datetime object and extract it using the `.dt.date` attribute. Finally, you may use `.astype(str)` to return the column to its original string format.

*Please be sure to change 'Date' to the correct name of your date column in the DataFrame.*

Answer (score 1):

Convert your column as [`DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) then [`normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) the time (*Convert times to midnight*):

```
df['Date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.normalize()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                  Date      Date2
0  2016-01-13 00:00:00 2016-01-13

>>> df.dtypes
Date             object
Date2    datetime64[ns]
```